# Parallel.ForEach Set MaxDegreeOfParallelism globally

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

Say I have a situation where I really want to use `Parallel.ForEach` instead of a regular `foreach` loop because it's much more performant (and way cooler), but having `.NET` determine the degree of parallelism for me leads to disastrous effects.

Now say that I've discovered the magic number that I need to place in the `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism` parameter so that my application is super tasty fast and not super tasty broken.

Instead of having to remember to include a `ParallelOptions` parameter with the magic number every time I invoke `Parallel.ForEach` (or any other derivative of it), is there any way to specify the degree of parallelism at the `web.config` level?  Or some other approach where the value can be set globally and invisibly so I don't have to rely on the memory of myself and fellow developers any time we want to gain the benefits of parallelism?

Comment: +1 I laughed out loud at the humor in your question, which is a mighty good one I might add. Now, 2 years later, do you know how to control the beast inside a recursive function? (had one answerer not been named "recursive" and given me this false hit, I would not have found your post...talk about your flukes :)

Comment: I"m not sure what you mean by "controlling the beast", but it sounds like a difficult task.  I'd say avoid the problem and hope someone else deals with it.

As for my question here, after two years of added experience, I've realized that if you're trying to leverage a technology that requires coordination among different human beings or else suffer great consequences, it's definitely not worth doing.  I ended up removing the calls to `Parallel.ForEach` where this concern applied and opted instead for less (yet still acceptable) performance.

Comment: I also realized that after two years of added experience, I'm a lot angrier than I used to be.  Too much coding, I guess.

Comment: Right I agree. I'm not going to try to control parallelism (the beast) there. I'm going to create 4 threads and give them each logic to avoid stepping on one another as they traverse the same tree. Thanks and "Anger Management for Dummies" worked for me (no joke there). :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is No, you can't configure this parameter using a config file, however you can still have a const variable that all your call can refer to.

Answer (score 1):

You could make your own wrapper function that calls `Parallel.Foreach` that reads the degree from a config file or from a constant.

Comment: That's a good idea, and probably the route I'd take if I couldn't find a way to somehow affect it globally.

It still doesn't address the issue of having to have a policy that everyone knows and abides by.  That's the risk I'm trying to avoid.